# how to load large text into textview

Tags: c#, gtk

I am loading a large text (100 000+ lines of text) and it takes a very long time for textview to display it. I understand that it's hard to load this amount of text, but is there at least a way to disable textview control until all text is loaded, so that user can't scroll it, or modify during it's being loaded into textview?

I would prefer to gray (sensitive = false) it and display "Loading" for time when it's loading the text rather. Or if it's possible, just load it some way that it is loaded instantly (for example render only part of text)

the code I am using right now is really very simple, the huge text is inside of StringBuilder

first variant:

```
// everything is StringBuilder
simpleview.Buffer.Text = everything.ToString();
if (ScrollingEnabled)
{
    simpleview.ScrollToIter(simpleview.Buffer.GetIterAtLine(ContentLines.Count), 0, true, 0, 0);
}
```

second one (it appears to me faster a bit)

```
            simpleview.Buffer.Text = "";
            simpleview.Buffer.InsertAtCursor(everything.ToString());
            if (ScrollingEnabled)
            {
                simpleview.ScrollToIter(simpleview.Buffer.GetIterAtLine(ContentLines.Count), 0, true, 0, 0);
            }
```

I don't need to display all text in one time, but I would like to make it possible for user to scroll and browse through all text if possible. Also I would like to notice that this is not just slow for 100 000 of lines, it's actually very slow even for 1000 lines and that is quite short piece of text...

Comment: Can you provide your existing code, currently I'd think of `LazyLoading`, `ASync`, or `Queue` may assist you.  Just depends on your route an implementation.

Comment: Do you really have to load 100,000+ lines of text at the same time? Is it possible if you could slice the data and display it when needed?

Comment: I answered both in question now